# Javascript: What are the pros/cons of adding methods to an object class?

Tags: javascript

I've seen some people add methods to the object class like so:

```
Object.clone = function() {

}
```

Is this syntax just like any other function name only with a period or is this actually adding to the Object class? Is this the same as a prototype method? What would be the pros/cons of doing this (or using a prototype) versus just making a function clone?

Comment: Some people say it's not wise to modify prototype objects such as `Object`, some people say it's okay. You may run into issues if other libraries also modify those objects. (Also begin countdown until this question is closed for being opinion based/unconstructive)

Comment: to "some people": why?

Comment: That thing is called the `Object` global constructor. It's one of the standard built-in constructors. It's not a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript everything is an object this means that you can attach properties to any object, just like you would with an object literal, for example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.property = 'foo';
```

It is not good practice to do so on non-objects though.

Every object has a constructor, so an array has an `Array` constructor, an object has an `Object` contructor, etc. The `prototype` of an object is an object whose context is the instance, this happens on custom objects when you instantiate with `new`.

When you attach a method to the `prototype` it will be shared across all instances of that object. When you attach a function to the constructor, you're basically hiding a global (depending on the scope) under a namespace; the context is not the instance, and it doesn't depend on one. You could think of these functions as static methods.

Extending `Object.prototype` is troublesome, since this is the "mother object". Extending the `Object` constructor itself isn't as bad, but not the best practice. The best solution, just create your own namespace:

```
var MY = {};

MY.clone = function(){};
```

Comment: One more thing: if I had function clone() and a 3rd party script  somehow defined that method, would there be conflict. Is that a reason to use "MY.clone"?

Comment: If it's in the global scope, yes, there would be a conflict. `MY` is always safe, assuming `MY` is unique (or as unique as possible).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to add static functions to the built-in `Object` constructor. There are also issues with code robustness if you do this, as some current and future environments may introduce built-in methods of the same name and then you have name collisions.

Just add your methods to your own objects.

Comment: Okay, but what do you mean by "your own objects." These are basic functions like cloning and merging objects.

Comment: @JohnSmith `var John = {}; John.merge = function () { ... }; John.clone = function () { ... };`